# How to restrict DisplayGrid.Always to show only maxCols and maxRows

Tags: angular, gridster, angular-gridster2

I want to restrict the grid lines to appear only till max number of rows and columns that I specified in configuration (12*12), however I could see more gridline than the specified layout, it's confusing to the user.

Here is the configuration

```
this.options = {
gridType: GridType.Fixed,
displayGrid: DisplayGrid.Always,
draggable: { enabled: false },
resizable: { enabled: false },
pushDirections: { north: false, east: true, south: false, west: true },
swap: true,
enableEmptyCellDrop: true,
emptyCellDropCallback: this.emptyCellClick.bind(this),
fixedRowHeight: 90,
fixedColWidth: 90,
maxCols:12,
maxRows:12,
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **gridType: GridType.Fixed** from the configuration. It does the job.